# How to filter one variable against multiple values in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

Hi I'm using Angular 5 and I want to filter an `Observable` of an array by an id against multiple ids from another array.

```
  onSelectedChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedAreas = [11,12,15,19,18,16,22];
    return this.readers$
       .map(projects => projects.filter(proj => proj.AreaId == 13||15||16||18)) // 
       .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
         this.filteredReaders = data;
    })
  }
```

I want something like select **where id in ids**

Comment: `proj => arrayObject.includes(proj.AreaId)`

Comment: Thanks , it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
this.selectedAreas.includes(proj.AreaId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array.indexOf

```
let possibleValues = [13,15,16,18]
projects.filter(proj => possibleValues.indexOf(proj.AreaId)!= -1)
```

and with ES6, you can use **[`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)**

```
this.selectedAreas.includes(proj.AreaId)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. This should do what you require

```
return this.readers$

   .map(projects => projects.filter(proj => [13, 15, 16, 18].includes(proj.AreaId))) 
   .subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
     this.filteredReaders = data;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use an array and `indexOf`

```
let possibleValues = [13,15,16,18]
projects.filter(proj => possibleValues.indexOf(proj.AreaId)!= -1)
```